# Add style to elements inside HTML5 canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I have the following code:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
context = canvas.getContext('2d')
canvas.width = window.innerWidth
canvas.height = 100
document.body.appendChild(canvas)

image = new Image()
image.src = 'http://units.wesnoth.org/1.5.10/pics/00006_flare.png'
image.style.border = '1px solid black'

document.body.appendChild(image)
context.drawImage(image, 5, 5)
```

You can view it on jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/notalex/6d78t/).

The style does not apply for the image rendered inside the Canvas. How does one apply style to elements inside canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting CSS styles only affects *elements*, here the image element.

When you draw the image to canvas you don't draw the element but the image's bitmap. Canvas is just that, a bitmap and is not related to CSS or DOM per-SE (it's a DOM element but everything that happens inside it is "low-level" bitmap manipulation).

To simulate border for an image drawn to canvas you can draw it on top:

```
context.drawImage(image, 5, 5);
context.lineWidth = 3;
context.strokeStyle = '#00f';
context.strokeRect(5, 5, image.width, image.height);
```

(offset the x and y position by 0.5 pixel to make the border sharp).

**[Modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/6d78t/3/)**

PS: Also remember to handle image loading properly using the `onload` handler as loading images is asynchronous (updated fiddle with this as well).

Comment: lineWidth defaults to 1 and strokeStyle to black so in the fiddle they're strictly not necessary.